# Handle No Match input with custom logic in Confirmation Intent using Actions SDK

Tags: actions-on-google

When I use the [Confirmation Helper Intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/helpers#confirmation) on an `Actions SDK` project, it works as it's supposed to. But I want to handle the case when the user's input doesn't mean either yes or no (a No Match situation). Currently Assistant automatically re-prompts the user in this situation.

Actions SDK provides the user's actual input when a confirmation is granted or denied. But is there any way to know what the user said in a No Match situation?

For example, let's say, in a `Confirmation` prompt, the user says: `"I just need some eggs. Just give me some eggs"`. This would cause Assistant to show the same prompt to the user again. It happens automatically and I have no way of accessing what the user actually said. If I want to do something when the user says "I just need some eggs" I can't do it because I can't access what the user is saying. Moreover, I haven't seen any Intent getting fired in this situation.

So, how can I handle No Match situations with custom logic instead of giving the default re-prompt to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to not use the confirmation helper and just create Intents that handle "yes" or "no" equivalents yourself.

Comment: I suppose that's what I have to end up doing. But it would make much more sense to be able to use the confirmation intent. Is this a standard practice that's followed?

Comment: I haven't met anyone that uses any of the helper intents unless they have to.